# How to link .asc / .pgp / etc. files with Kleopatra on Windows?

Tags: windows, gnupg, pgp

Having an *.asc or *.pgp file on e-mail attachments displayed in Thunderbird, but also having files with these extensions on the harddrive: How do I link them with Kleopatra (always open with), on Windows 7? So when I double click the file, it automatically opens in Kleopatra.

Comment: After many trial and error attempts as well as scouring Kleopatra's documentation, I do not thing you can.

I am not sure if this is due to how Windows handles certificates, or if it is due to Kleopatra's design as it does not know what to do with the file.

Comment: @Tim Maybe you need to choose the program thats embedded in Windows context menu to open the file - I couldnt find its path. And have u tried GPA or GnuPG directly, cause if they can import the file, it should appear at Kleopatra too since they are the same keyfile, right? I had no luck.

Comment: Is the Goal of opening it with kleo to automatically add it to your keys?

Comment: @Tim yes, so its known to my GnuPG setup with Kleopatra and Thunderbird and I can work with it (verify, decrypt, encryp, etc.)

Comment: I was not able to get it to go on my end.